# how can I add a number to an id inside of a for loop in jquery?

Tags: jquery, for-loop, jquery-selectors, element

I want to reproduce a ton of click functions without copy and pasting them all the way down the page and then changing individual numbers. My problem is I cannot get the ID's to change inside my for loop.

Here is my script:

```
for (var i=0;i<$('.slide').length;i++) {
            $step = $('#step'+i);
            $step.on('click', slideTo);
            function slideTo(event){
                $(this).off('click');
                $active = $('.current');
                if (!$active.is('#slide'+i)) {
                    $active.animate({
                        left: '-1024px'
                    }, 500, function() {
                        $(this).removeClass('current');
                    });
                    $('#slide'+i).animate({
                        left: '0'
                    }, 500, function() {
                        $(this).addClass('current');
                        $step.on('click', slideTo);
                    }).addClass('current');
                };
            };
        }
```

There is alot of HTML but for now here is a little bit:

```
<div id="slider" class="article">
            <div id="slideHolder">
                <!-- Step 1 -->  
                <div class="walkthrough firstClass current">
                    <div class="step">
                        <h4>STEP 1: Go to the DRMA Service Center.</h4><p>From the RII Homepage <a href="http://r2.nrc.gov" target="_blank" title="">(r2.nrc.gov,)</a> Look under where it says Quicklinks. The second link from the top of the list is the link to the DRMA Service Center. You can click there or click the link below the image to the right. >>></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stepImg">
                        <img src="img/step1.jpg" alt="" />
                        <a href="" title="">Think you got it? Exit to the DRMA Service Center >>></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clr"></div>
                </div>
    <!-- Step 2 -->         
                <div class="walkthrough">
                    <div class="step">
                        <h4>STEP 2: LOGIN.</h4><p>Here you want to log in just as you would to your Region II workstation.<br /><br />Username: Your LAN ID<br />Password: Your regular NRC Password</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stepImg">
                        <img src="img/step2.jpg" alt="" />
                        <a href="" title="">Think you got it? Exit to the DRMA Service Center >>></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clr"></div>
                </div>
</div>
</div>
        <div id="sliderControls">
            <div class="slide" id="step1">Step 1</div>
            <div class="slide" id="step2">Step 2</div>
</div>
```

If you need me to add anything just ask, Thanks.

Comment: What is the effect you want when you click step(i) ?

Comment: I need this to change inside the for loop  $step = $('#step'+i);

Comment: It already does but you have many errors in the code after so I want to know what you want to happen so I can try to help.

Comment: What do you want/expect with `if (!$active.is('#slide'+i))` ?

Comment: when I click the button, I want to move a <div class="walkthrough"> off and then move one on and turn the button functionality off then back on during the aqnimation.

Comment: what errors are you referring to?

Comment: ultimately, I just need to know how to append to a selector

Comment: Well your loop is working, you may want to start loop with i=1 because you don't have a step0. Check here and press step1, step 2 http://jsfiddle.net/sVw8n/